# For hot air at 150 °C have a density of 0.61 kg / m³, how to calculate the density for 160 °C?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, density, air, humidity

I am working on a project draft and in an existing device, hot air up to 160 °C is generated for drying processes.
I have found old documents where densities of air are reported at three different temperatures:

30 °C --> 1.16 kg/m³

100 °C --> 0.84 kg/m³

150 °C --> 0.61 kg / m³

Now I used tables to confirm those values (and also asked ChatGPT) and came up to following values:

30 °C --> 1.16 kg/m³

100 °C --> 0.95 kg/m³

150 °C --> 0.83 kg / m³

I think my values are for dry air and above values are for humid air. Using ChatGPT I came to a relative humidity of 30% for the reported values. That makes sense. But above 100 °C the calculation is not trivial because then I get superheated steam/air.

I need the density of air at 160 °C with the relative humidity assumed in the above reported ones.

I know that if the temperature is increased, the relative humidity AND the density should decrease, but I don't know how to calculate. Online calculators go only to 90, max 100 °C.

Comment: It seems like the humidity of the air would be strongly determined by the "drying process" that you use it for. Without further details not much can be said about it. (Or maybe you are assuming the inlet air is just ambient air and then heated before the drying process starts? Please specify...)

Comment: Thanks! Thats correct. I am assuming that the inlet air is ambient air which is heated up to 160 °C. For further efficiency and energetic calculatioins I need to know the density. I can lookup the density for 160 °C dry air. But in the old report they assumed some other humidity because when I use a calculator and type 100 °C and assume 30 % RH, I come up to the same density, namely: 0,84 kg / m³

Comment: [This handbook](https://macinstruments.com/wp-content/uploads/handbook.pdf) talks somewhat about what "relative humidity" means above 100°C, as well as other ways to measure moisture content of air.

Comment: Are you assuming that some water enters or leaves the system as the air mass circulates?  Relative humidity is just the ratio of the density of water vapour to the saturation density, and the saturation density is highly temperature dependent.  Sof the *relative* humidity stays constant at 30% while the temperature changes, that means that the absolute density of water vapour in the air will change.

Comment: Sry I wasn't pecise. For the drying the starting humidity is 30 %. The air is heatet up and diverted to the object of interest to dry it. My only interesit is after the heating and before the contact with the object. Afaik, the RH decreases sharply with increasing temperature of the ambient air, so does the density.